# JSON Array Iteration - Tree Traversing in Mulesoft 4

Tags: arrays, xml, dataweave, mule4

Input JSON:

```json
     {
        "id": "/",
        "code": "/",
        "typeCode": "CPC",
        "timeStamp": "2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00",
        "childList": [
            {
                "id": "577-1-1",
                "code": "1111",
                "name": "Electronics-1-1",
                "displayName": "Electronics-1-1",
                "active": true,
                "languageCode": "en",
                "typeCode": "CPC",
                "childList": [
                    {
                        "id": "579-2-1",
                        "code": "2222",
                        "name": "Calculators-2-1",
                        "displayName": "Calculators-2-1",
                        "active": true,
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "typeCode": "CPC",
                        "childList": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "509-2-2",
                        "code": "3333",
                        "name": "Oven-2-2",
                        "displayName": "Oven-2-2",
                        "active": true,
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "typeCode": "CPC",
                        "childList": [
                            {
                                "id": "749-3-1",
                                "code": "4444",
                                "name": "MicroOven-3-1",
                                "displayName": "MicroOven-3-1",
                                "active": true,
                                "languageCode": "en",
                                "typeCode": "CPC",
                                "childList": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "549-1-2",
                "code": "5555",
                "name": "Toys, Crafts & Leisure",
                "displayName": "Toys, Crafts & Leisure",
                "active": true,
                "languageCode": "en",
                "typeCode": "CPC",
                "childList": [
                    {
                        "id": "49674",
                        "code": "7605",
                        "name": "Pet Supplies",
                        "displayName": "Pet Supplies",
                        "active": true,
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "typeCode": "CPC",
                        "childList": [
                            {
                                "id": "49684",
                                "code": "7615",
                                "name": "Beds & Houses",
                                "displayName": "Beds & Houses",
                                "active": true,
                                "languageCode": "en",
                                "typeCode": "CPC",
                                "childList": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "58782",
                "code": "0100",
                "name": "Fashion (new)",
                "displayName": "Fashion",
                "active": true,
                "languageCode": "en",
                "typeCode": "CPC",
                "childList": [
                    {
                        "id": "49056",
                        "code": "6958",
                        "name": "Blazers & Jackets, Etc. - Department",
                        "displayName": "Blazers & Jackets, Etc.",
                        "active": true,
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "typeCode": "CPC",
                        "childList": [
                            {
                                "id": "50851",
                                "code": "7837",
                                "name": "Dusters PDM Name",
                                "displayName": "Dusters PDM Display Name",
                                "active": true,
                                "languageCode": "en",
                                "typeCode": "CPC",
                                "childList": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

1. And the expected XML is as below - Here the categoryPath has to be noted for the complete address of childElement and has to be grouped under 1st parent childList
2. We will not know the exact child elements of any array i.e., there can be ‘n’ number of childList inside a childList
3. How many elements are present in 1st childlist array - those many CategoryList elements has to be formed in xml

Note:  here I have just taken 2 elements as an example - but any childlist array can have any number of childlists array inside it.

XML Transformation:

```
<Category CategoryId="${childList.code}" CategoryPath="${childList.code}/${childList.childList.code}" Description="${childList.displayName}" ShortDescription="${childList.name}">
    <Extn ExtnSyncTS="${headers.timeStamp}"/>
</Category>
```

Expected XML:

```
<CategoryListArray>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="1111" CategoryPath="1111" Description="Electronics-1-1" ShortDescription="Electronics-1-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="2222" CategoryPath="1111/2222" Description="Calculators-2-1" ShortDescription="Calculators-2-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS=" "/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="3333" CategoryPath="1111/3333" Description="Oven-2-2" ShortDescription="Oven-2-2">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="4444" CategoryPath="1111/3333/4444" Description="MicroOven-3-1" ShortDescription="MicroOven-3-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="5555" CategoryPath="5555" Description="Toys, Crafts & Leisure" ShortDescription="Toys, Crafts & Leisure">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7605" CategoryPath="5555/7605" Description="Pet Supplies" ShortDescription="Pet Supplies">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7615" CategoryPath="5555/7605/7615" Description="Beds & Houses" ShortDescription="Beds & Houses">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="0100" CategoryPath="0100" Description="Fashion" ShortDescription="Fashion (new)">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="6958" CategoryPath="0100/6958" Description=""Blazers & Jackets, Etc." ShortDescription="Blazers & Jackets, Etc. - Department">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7837" CategoryPath="0100/6958/7837" Description="Dusters PDM Display Name" ShortDescription="Dusters PDM Name">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
</CategoryListArray>
```

Comment: What's the criteria to group each Category into CategoryList elements?

Comment: Based on 1st parent childList.. If the input json has 20 1st parent childlist then 20 messages has to be sent by mulesoft.. and all other childlists inside the 1st parent has to be grouped in a categorylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my previous answer to support the new output. I used a nested function to reuse the previous method untouched while adding for the changes at the top, so there is only one function visible to the script.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

fun mapToCategoriesArrayList(data) = do {
    fun mapChildren(x, timestamp, path)=
        x match {
            case o is Object -> 
                ([{
                    Category @(CategoryId: o.id, CategoryPath: (if (isEmpty(path)) "" else path ++ "/") ++ o.code, Description: o.name, ShortDescription: o.displayName ): {Extn: timestamp}
                }] 
                ++ mapChildren(o.childList, timestamp, (if (isEmpty(path)) "" else path ++ "/") ++ o.code)) 
            
            case a is Array -> 
                (a flatMap mapChildren($, timestamp, path) )
                
            else -> $
        }
    ---
    {
        CategoryListArray: 
            ( 
                data.childList map { 
                    CategoryList:
                          mapChildren($, data.timeStamp, "") 
                          reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item ) 
                }
            ) reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item ) 
    }
}
---
mapToCategoriesArrayList(payload)
```

Output:

```json
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<CategoryListArray>
  <CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="577-1-1" CategoryPath="1111" Description="Electronics-1-1" ShortDescription="Electronics-1-1">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="579-2-1" CategoryPath="1111/2222" Description="Calculators-2-1" ShortDescription="Calculators-2-1">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="509-2-2" CategoryPath="1111/3333" Description="Oven-2-2" ShortDescription="Oven-2-2">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="749-3-1" CategoryPath="1111/3333/4444" Description="MicroOven-3-1" ShortDescription="MicroOven-3-1">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
  </CategoryList>
  <CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="549-1-2" CategoryPath="5555" Description="Toys, Crafts &amp; Leisure" ShortDescription="Toys, Crafts &amp; Leisure">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="49674" CategoryPath="5555/7605" Description="Pet Supplies" ShortDescription="Pet Supplies">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="49684" CategoryPath="5555/7605/7615" Description="Beds &amp; Houses" ShortDescription="Beds &amp; Houses">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
  </CategoryList>
  <CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="58782" CategoryPath="0100" Description="Fashion (new)" ShortDescription="Fashion">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="49056" CategoryPath="0100/6958" Description="Blazers &amp; Jackets, Etc. - Department" ShortDescription="Blazers &amp; Jackets, Etc.">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="50851" CategoryPath="0100/6958/7837" Description="Dusters PDM Name" ShortDescription="Dusters PDM Display Name">
      <Extn>2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00</Extn>
    </Category>
  </CategoryList>
</CategoryListArray>
```

Update: fixed CategoryList grouping

Comment: from the above dw code also, the output structure is same as earlier.. my current o/p structure is changed.. i need all category's of 1st parent child in json under one categoryList.
But i made few changes in brackets and it is working - thanks

Comment: I made a mistake in the grouping of CategoryList. I updated the answer to fix it.

Comment: Hi @aled I just wanted to handle null values also., can you tell me if it is possible to be done with few changes., null values mean => if there are no any child elements inside a category, then the childList can be empty array(as in case above) or childList can be null..for example: ..."childList": [{"id": "579-2-1","code": "2222","name": "Calculators-2-1",                        "displayName": "Calculators-2-1", "active": true,"languageCode": "en","typeCode": "CPC", "childList": null },....

Comment: Please ask in a new question.